# nested segues app performance

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to use a tab bar on top of the view controller not in the bottom. after searching, i found out it's against Apple's UI Interface Guidelines and it should always be at the bottom. However, my app has to have also one at the top. Anyway, i was thinking of using nested segues. For example, if we have three view controllers that each has 3 buttons on top that resemble the tab bar items, and i'm positioned on the first VC (hence, the first button is highlighted). When i press on the second button it gets highlighted and segues to the second VC. Then if i press of the first button, i'll be taken back to the first VC. My question here is if i worked using this paradigm, will the VC's be stacked? will the performance of the app decrease? can i achieve this in a better way in case the answer of the previous questions were negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these projects

1. [MHCustomTabBarController](https://github.com/mhaddl/MHCustomTabBarController)
2. [ICViewPager](https://github.com/monsieurje/ICViewPager)
3. [JCMSegmentPageController](https://github.com/jcmendez/JCMSegmentPageController)
4. [QMBTabs](https://github.com/quemb/QMBTabs)